# React and Firebase: onAuthStateChanged problem, state update on unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my Context file, and I have my App.js wrapped with the AuthProvider:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => setUser(user));

        return () => { unsubscribe(); }
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

This is one of those consumer component.

```
function PurchasesNSales() {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const history = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user) 
            history("/", { replace: true });
    }, [user, history]);

    return(
        <p>Welcome {user?.displayName}</p>
    );
}

export default PurchasesNSales;
```

If I remove the useEffect on the second file, everything works fine, but if I do that I am not verifying authentication of the user.

I am most likely doing something wrong.

From what I understand I am trying to setState on a component that is already unmounted, which I don't understand where that is happening.

I am on my Dashboard page, I press the button which should take me to the "PurchasesNSales" page and that is when the error occurs.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-frog-gmkk5?file=/src/components/PurchasesNSales/PurchasesNSales.js) Hopefully this sample app helps.

Comment: Try to create a codesandbox with sample code

Comment: Will do, once I'm home again!